# Azure acs ssh login keeping failing with "permission denied (public key)"

Tags: azure, ssh, containers, azure-cli

I have successfully deployed a mesos cluster on azure container service using article [deploy an container service cluster](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/container-service-deployment/). I used azure cli on OS X for creating the cluster. As part of the process I created a new ssh key pair:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
```

After deployment went successful I'm trying to [ssh into the end point](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/container-service-connect/) but receiving "Permission Denied (Public Key)"

```
 ssh -L 80:localhost:80 -N azureuser@xyz.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com -p 2200 -v
```

The verbose [not all but last few lines]

```
debug1: Host '[xyz.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com]:2200' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I don't recall any issues while creating the ssh keys but may be something I've missed just not sure what it cloud be.

Comment: Hi Did the solution work for you?

Comment: For future reference: Create a new key pair:    `sudo ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f acs_key`  then establish connection using the key `ssh -i ~/acs/ssh_keys/acs_key -L 80:localhost:80 -N azureuser@xyz.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com -p 2200 -v `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not using local port forwarding, following worked for me :  `ssh -i /<path>/id_rsa  username@masteralias.westus.cloudapp.azure.com -p 2200 -v`.

Also if you try creating the cluster using https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-acs-mesos, in the parameter screen you are told the following regarding the key (in tooltip) "Configure all linux machines with the SSH RSA public key string. Your key should 
include three parts, for example 'ssh-rsa AAAAB...snip...UcyupgH azureuser@linuxvm" . So please make sure that your key has 3 parts as mentioned

Comment: Yes, using the -i switch resoleved the issue. Also using port fowarding and its working as expected. Here is the actual working command:                                                                           `ssh -i ~/acs/ssh_keys/acs_key -L 80:localhost:80 -N azureuser@xyz.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com -p 2200 -v`